# Can a timespec have more than 1 seconds worth of nanoseconds in the tv_nsec field?

Tags: c, linux, time

Im working with the `clock_gettime()` command and trying to append a given amount of milliseconds to the `timespec` that I get from it.  Can I just do this?

```
//milli is an int that can be any number (within reason)
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
ts.tv_nesc += (milli*1000000);
```

or do I need to split it up and find out if there are any whole seconds first, add those to the `tv_sec` field, and then add the remaining to the `tv_nsec`?

Essentially, can the `tv_nsec` field store more than 1 seconds worth of nanoseconds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you're going to do with it.

The `tv_nsec` members of a `struct timespec` is of type `long`. You can set it to any value you like in the range `LONG_MIN` to `LONG_MAX`. If you perform a calculation that exceeds `LONG_MAX`, which is at least 2<sup>31</sup>-1, then you're going to have problems (undefined behavior that will *probably* show up as the value wrapping around).

Whether setting it to a value less than 0, or greater than or equal to one billion, will cause a problem depends on what you do with it. If you just want to print it, or perform some calculations on it, any valid `long` value should be ok -- but the stored values are probably more useful if you normalize them.

`clock_gettime()` should always give you a `tv_nsec` value in the range 0..999999999.

POSIX requires the `clock_settime()`, `clock_nanosleep()`, and `nanosleep()` functions to fail, and set `errno` to `EINVAL`, if "The *tp* argument specified a nanosecond value less than zero or greater than or equal to 1000 million."

References:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_settime.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html

Comment: +1. But it's worth explaining _how_ to do this. If you want to be completely POSIX/C portable, you have to check for overflow in advance of the addition, etc., which is no fun. If you just want to work on every practical POSIX platform (and aren't ever adding a denormalized timespec or more than 1G nanos), you can make the usual assumptions about how `long` works, which is pretty simple. If you only care about linux, you can use `timespec_add_safe`/`timespec_add` or `set_normalized_timespec`, which do all of it for you.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  I've followed  your link to the posix std. It looks like the POSIX garantee you're talking about is defined for clock_settime(). "The clock_settime() function shall fail if:" . Or did I miss something? Because actually I am interested in such a garantee! :-)

Comment: @yvesBaumes: I've just cleaned up my answer a bit. What guarantee are you asking about?

Comment: @KeithThompson I was talking about that assertion "clock_gettime() should always give you a tv_nsec value in the range 0..999999999". But I asked a dedicated question then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029624/when-invoking-clock-gettime-may-the-returned-tv-nsec-field-actually-exceed-a-s

Answer (score 1):

A `tv_nsec` field will tolerate a *limited* amount of nanosecond overflow (always enough to add two valid timespec nanosecond values, so, 999999999 + 999999999 = 1999999998).  There is no guarantee that an arbitrary amount of overflow will work, though: on implementations with 32-bit `long`, you can only go up to just over two seconds' worth of nanoseconds, to 2.147483647 seconds.  So if someone tells you to add 2500 milliseconds (2.5 seconds), that would overflow.

Edit to add: and, as Keith Thompson notes, you need to re-normalize after adding one timespec to another.